# Is there a way to tell Fish shell to correct common typos in commands with spaces?

Tags: alias, fish, abbreviation

I'm fairly new to Fish, and I like it so far, but I'm annoyed that abbreviations can't have spaces. For example, when I type `git statsu`, which I do more often than the actual command of `git status`, I want it to replace the text with the correct command. I have tried adding the following to my `config.fish` file:

```
abbr "git statsu" "git status"
```

…which gives me:

```
abbr --add: Abbreviation 'git statsu' cannot have spaces in the word
```

Second try (*alias with spaces not supported*):

```
alias "git statsu"="git status"
```

```
- (line 1): function: Unexpected positional argument 'statsu'
function git statsu --wraps 'git status' --description 'alias git statsu=git status';  git status $argv; end
^
from sourcing file -
    called on line 61 of file /usr/share/fish/functions/alias.fish
in function 'alias' with arguments 'git\ statsu=git\ status'
    called on line 19 of file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
    called on line 1 of file -
in function 'config'
```

Similarly, I try:

```
alias "git\ statsu"="git\ status"
```

Which fails silently:

```
> git statsu
git: 'statsu' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
    status
```

And finally (*abbreviations after first argument not expanded*):

```
abbr statsu status
```

```
> git statsu
git: 'statsu' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
    status
```

Please offer alternative solutions; I am tired of constantly typing the wrong command and having to correct it manually.

Comment: The whole point of abbreviations is to greatly reduce the number of characters typed. So rather than trying to define `abbr "git statsu" "git status"` do `abbr gs "git status"`. I have several abbreviations of that sort: `gb` => `git branch`, `gl` => `git log --stat -100`, `gca` => `git commit --amend`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use git aliases instead. Here are a couple of mine:

```sh
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
...
[alias]
    co = checkout
    stat = status
```

---

Here's a fish thing you can do that's easy to expand with other common typos:

```
function git
    switch $argv[1]
        case statsu
            set argv[1] status
    end
    command git $argv
end
```

Comment: This will work great for this specific case, but I fear that I or others will run into this same, general expansion issue outside of using git. Is there a more generic solution readily available? Or is it better practice to take this on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: Personally, I prefer Fish (or Elvish) abbreviations. Such as `abbr gs "git status"`. Especially since that doesn't require command specific support and is far shorter to type for a very common case. If I'm not running the command interactively there is little justification for the `git` specific alias.